# Get coordinates of my series in jFreechart

Tags: java, arraylist, jfreechart

I have:

```
XYSeries series = new XYSeries("My Function");
```

After some operation i have do some add as this:

```
series.add(x,y);
```

X and Y are int.

So, i have also an arrayList seriesCoeff;

After this declaration i would execute this operation:

```
double[][] myCoeff == new double[2][3];
for (int i=0; series.iterator.hasNext; i++) {
if (//x coordinate of series in position i// == myX && //y coordinate of series i  position i// == myY)
//seriesCoeff in position i// == myCoeff;
```

Can you help me to get coordinates of my series?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`XYSeries` has `getX()` and `getY()` that you can use in your loop:

```
double x = series.getX(0).doubleValue();
double y = series.getY(0).doubleValue();
```